# Tomcat Resource Factory org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: No provider available for resource-env-ref

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee

I am using TomEE as the Application Server. TomEE uses Tomcat 7. I have the following code:

```
package com.jndi;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.RefAddr;
import javax.naming.Reference;
import javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory;


public class GitObjectFactory implements ObjectFactory {

public GitObjectFactory() {

}

public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable     environment) throws NamingException {
    GitConnection gitConnection = new GitConnection();
    // Customize the bean properties from our attributes
    Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
    RefAddr refAddr = ref.get("gitLocation");
    String value = (String) refAddr.getContent();
    gitConnection.setGitLocation(value);
    return gitConnection;
}
}

public class GitConnection {

private String gitLocation;

public GitConnection() {

}

public String getGitLocation() {
    return gitLocation;
}

public void setGitLocation(String gitLocation) {
    this.gitLocation = gitLocation;
}
 }

in context.xml
<Context>

<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource name='git/GitConnectionFactory' auth='Container'
type='com.jndi.GitConnection'
factory='com.jndi.GitObjectFactory'
gitLocation='C:\jGitClone\.git'/>
```

in web.xml
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

```
     <context-param>
        <!-- Specifies the list of Spring Configuration files in comma separated format.-->

        /WEB-INF/spring/email.xml
     </context-param>

     <listener>
        <!-- Loads your Configuration Files-->
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
     </listener>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>i</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>i</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>

     <resource-env-ref>
        <description>Object Factory for GitConnection instances.</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>git/GitConnectionFactory</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>com.jndi.GitConnection</resource-env-ref-type>
     </resource-env-ref>     
 </web-app>

When I load Tomcat, I can see successfully that the resource git/GitConnectionFactory is registered:

 INFO: Configuring Service(id=git/GitConnectionFactory, type=Resource, provider-id=ProvidedByTomcat)
```

06-Apr-2013 17:54:25 org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe

As soon as I deploy the application I get the following Exception:

```
  org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: No provider available for resource-env-ref 'git/GitConnectionFactory' of type 'com.jndi.GitConnection' for 'i'.
```

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: does the `GitConnectionFactory` have a `register` method for the specific class u want?

Comment: what do you mean? The code above is what I know.

Comment: I believe the register is the GitObjectFactory.

Comment: I am not sure, I had similar issue with JDBC drivers, and I had to `register` the driver although it was imported and such.

Comment: [**CDI 1.0 vs. Spring 3.1 feature comparsion: bean definition & dependency injection**](http://java.dzone.com/articles/cdi-10-vs-spring-31-feature)

Comment: Something similar to this: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/openejb-users/200808.mbox/%3C18952298.post@talk.nabble.com%3E

Comment: How did you register it?

Comment: When deploying the application directly into Tomcat 7, it works perfectly. It is something to do with TomEE Plus. Although it contains Tomcat 7.